# Using multiple font sizes in Plotly chart title (Python)

Tags: python, charts, fonts, formatting, plotly

I have a chart title which spans multiple lines using line breaks.

I'd like to have everything after the first line in a smaller font (effectively a subtitle), but can't figure out a way to do this.

Couldn't see any similar question on here.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
data=[]
layout = go.Layout(title='line1' + '<br>' +  'line2')
fig = go.FigureWidget(data=data, layout=layout)
fig
```

Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can use `<span>` tags with CSS, like this:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
data=[]
layout = go.Layout(title='line1' + '<br>' +  '<span style="font-size: 12px;">line2</span>')
fig = go.FigureWidget(data=data, layout=layout)
fig
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome. Works perfectly. Thanks so much for taking the time to respond.

Comment: Is there a way to put this in my style.css file? i.e. .customTitle and use it in multiple graphs project wide? Can I then access it with <span class=.customTitle>...</span>?

Answer (score 8):

You may use the following method:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.data as data

df = data.gapminder()

fig = px.histogram(df, x='continent')

fig.update_layout(
    height=400,
    title=dict(
        text='<b>Life Expectancy - Our World in Data</b>',
        x=0.5,
        y=0.95,
        font=dict(
            family="Arial",
            size=20,
            color='#000000'
        )
    ),
    xaxis_title="<b>Continent</b>",
    yaxis_title='<b>Average Age</b>',
    font=dict(
        family="Courier New, Monospace",
        size=12,
        color='#000000'
    )
)
fig.show()
```

[image: Figure using original solution]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y417t.png)

**Update: 16-March-2023**:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.data as data

df = data.gapminder()

fig = px.histogram(df, x='continent')

fig.update_layout(
    height=400,
    title=dict(
        text='<b><span style="font-family: Courier New, Monospace; font-size: 30pt">Life Expectancy</span> - <span style="font-family: Cursive;"> Our World in Data</span></b>',
        x=0.5,
        y=0.95,
    ),
    xaxis_title="<b>Continent</b>",
    yaxis_title='<b>Average Age</b>',
    font=dict(
        family="Courier New, Monospace",
        size=12,
        color='#000000'
    )
)
fig.show()
```

[image: Figure with new solution]

Comment: This answer does not show how to use multiple font sizes within the same title, which was the basis of the original poster's question.

Comment: See the updated solution.

Comment: Thank you for the update! It now answers the original question.