# Responsive Text in Plotly

Tags: python, fonts, formatting, plotly, responsive

I'm working on a dash app and trying to account for different screen sizes by using responsive text in plotly.

This is somewhat similar to this question: [Using Multiple Font Sizes in Plotly Chart Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57919281/using-multiple-font-sizes-in-plotly-chart-title-python/73158586?noredirect=1#comment129206940_73158586).

Doing something like this worked for the main title and axis titles:

```
fig.update_xaxes(
        {'title': '<span style = "font-size: 1.25vw">xAxis_Title</span>')
```

but I'm trying to do the same for the axis text so that the tickfont is responsive as well.

However, trying the same technique for tickfont did not work and results in errors,

```
fig.update_xaxes({'tickfont': '<span style = "size: 1vw"></span>'})
```

anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.